# Volumetrics - Different results GPU vs CPU

Tags: gpu, volumetrics

Hey fellow Blendy people,

I'm running some benchmark comparisons between various render engines involving a lot of small, simple scenes.

Anyway, on my test scene for volumetrics, I'm noticing a large discrepancy between GPU and CPU rendering. All other settings in the scene are identical.
Any ideas? I've never come accross this before, though to be fair I rarely render on CPU.

As you can see from the picture below, it's as though the volumetric density is different.

[image: Example of Volumetrics discrepancy]

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Bill

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do volumetrics render noisier when using GPU then when using CPU in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158472/why-do-volumetrics-render-noisier-when-using-gpu-then-when-using-cpu-in-cycles)

Comment: It looks like more of a discrepancy with density than a noise difference. In the GPU render the background is obscured by the fog, but the CPU render isn't behaving in the same way.

Comment: You're right, seems like it. Is that light a circular area light pointing at the camera or something like a point light or mesh light?

Comment: I wish this was mentioned somewhere in the Blender when switching between GPU and CPU rendering. Only yesterday I learned that GPU and CPU renders aren't always identical. (Arnold possibly being the one exception?)